# How do I add a onclick function to a custom React Component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-component

I am new to React. I have 3 buttons which are imported as a Component into App.js as:

```
import Button from "./Button";
```

I want to add an onClick function to these Components as:

```
<div className="buttonsdiv">
        <Button text="+" / onClick = {...}>
//text is a parameter defined in Button.js
        <Button text="RESET" onClick = {...} />
        <Button text="-"onClick = {...} />
      </div>
```

Is there a way to do it?

Comment: It will depend on the implementation of `Button` that you imported. It will have to use the `onClick` prop that you pass it.

Comment: You could pass the onclick function as a prop to Button component. Lets call it onClickProp. Then in your Button component you must have: <button onClick={this.props.onClickProp} />

Comment: Button component will be like: <Button onClickProp={this.a} />

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @BrianThompson said, it's all about the implementation of your `Button` component. The idea is to pass the `onClick` prop to the rendered html element, i.e.:

```
const Button = (props) => {
    return (
        <button onClick={props.onClick}/>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's a functional component, try this:

**JavaScript**

```
 const add = (e) => { }
 const sub = (e) => { }
 const reset = (e) => { }
```

**JSX**

```
  <div className="buttonsdiv">
    <Button text="+" onclick={add} />
    <Button text="RESET" onclick={reset} />
    <Button text="-" onclick={sub} />
  </div>
```

If it's a component without state, pass the functions to the component, like this:

```
const component = (props) => {
    return { 
      <div className="buttonsdiv">
        <Button text="+" onclick={props.add} />
        <Button text="RESET" onclick={props.reset} />
        <Button text="-" onclick={props.sub} />
      </div>
    }
}
```